# opengl vbo dma array

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo, dma

I am creating an array of positions to draw and I am stuck when I am using dma for the array

if I declare the size of the array and populate I can get it to work but if I do

```
float *datac;
datac=NULL;
datac = new float[12];

datac[0] = 0;datac[1] = 0;datac[2] = 0;
datac[3] = 0;datac[4] = 100;datac[5] = 0;
datac[6] = 100;datac[7] = 100;datac[8] = 0;
datac[9] = 100;datac[10] = 0;datac[11] = 0;

//how do I pass it through to these functions
//this is what I was using when I done float datac[12] = ....
//I have tried using this sizeof(*datac)*sizeof(float)
//which compiles but just does not draw

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(datac), datac, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, sizeof(datac)/ sizeof(float) / 3);
```

Being dull and I cant think what I need to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's C++, so you can use `std::vector` and make your life easy:

```
std::vector<float> datac(12);

datac[0] = 0;datac[1] = 0;datac[2] = 0;
datac[3] = 0;datac[4] = 100;datac[5] = 0;
datac[6] = 100;datac[7] = 100;datac[8] = 0;
datac[9] = 100;datac[10] = 0;datac[11] = 0;

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, datac.size()*sizeof(float), &datac[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
// glVertexPointer in GL2 or glAttribPointer in GL3 comes here
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, datac.size() / 3);
```

Comment: Thanks, just got it going with std::vector

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter to glBufferData should be `sizeof(float) * 12`.

You also need to specify your arrays with the `gl*Pointer` functions. You seem to be using Vec3s for your vertices, I belive the default is Vec4.  For example:

```
GLuint VertexBuf;
glGenBuffers(1, &VertexBuf);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBuf);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*12, datac, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, sizeof(float) * (12 / 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. is the second parameter to glBufferData

```
sizeof(datac)*12
```

Edit: corrected per comments

sizeof(float)*12

Comment: I realised that after I posted but I don't know how large the array will be. What Is a safe way to get the length of the array?

Comment: well you are allocating the datac at some point right? So you should be knowing the size of the array, the same one you are passing to new at datac = new float[*]

Comment: WOW, that was a real dull moment.  Thanks.

Comment: Technically, `sizeof(datac)` isn't right, it should be `sizeof(float)`.  `sizeof(float*)` isn't always the same as `sizeof(float)`, although they are probably the same on 32-bit platforms.

Comment: @tkerwin. Yes of course, thanks. datac is a pointer. You really need the size of float.

Comment: sizeof(datac[0]) would work for most cases, taking a dependency on the actual data size of an array element, not hard coding 'float' in there because you happen to know it's a float. I prefer to dereference a pointer/element in a sizeof so it will automatically work if it changes type. I don't like hard coding times 12, you probably have a struct type somewhere that you would use and take sizeof an array element of that type.